# Access Patterns Dynamo DB possible with a NoSQL Database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am relativly new to NoSQL Database Structures.

In my thinking the following access patterns show relations and analytical queries. But then a SQL Data Structure would be the better approach instead of a NoSQL Structure.

I wondering whether the following access patterns are even possible with a dynamoDB or maybe one has to get the data first from the DynamoDB into e.g. a lambda to process them.

```
Get all customers of this month that increased their spending higher then 25% compared to the last month
```

```
Get anual spending of a customer (Only monthly spending is entered into DynamoDB)
```

```
Get customers that has a spending over 0 in a specific timeframe
```

```
Get all orders in a specific timeframe and where the customer who placed the order has the following attributes (female, 25 yars, 170cm tall)
```

```
Get all active customers, active supplyers software, active supplyers raw materials for a given timeframe
```

Comment: How would you design an RDBMS schema to efficiently query for "all customers of this month that increased their spending higher than 25% compared to the last month"?

Comment: The thing is, when i would design the schema i directly think of relational databases structures instead of a NoSQL structure. Its a analytical access pattern and in my thinking when it comes to relations and analytical queries a SQL approach would be better then a NoSQL approach.

Comment: Right, but the query that I mentioned probably isn't something that you would calculate on the fly from 100k individual sales per month, I'm assuming. You'd maybe have some kind of maintained aggregation. You can do the same kind of thing with DynamoDB, via Streams. If you think about what queries you are going to need (and that's pretty much a requirement when using NoSQL) then you can create derived aggregations such as "sales of X by month", "annual spend by customer". Not saying that it's easy, of course, and NoSQL is often not the right choice.

Comment: May be helpful: [How to determine if Amazon DynamoDB is appropriate for your needs, and then plan your migration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-determine-if-amazon-dynamodb-is-appropriate-for-your-needs-and-then-plan-your-migration/).